# What would the perfect digital government look like?

Tags: government, utopia

If there was some form of government which actually ended the power struggle on Earth, and provided equal access to resources and information for everyone, and which could be managed completely by its constituents via a website and mobile app, what would the key features be? What would it be called?

Comment: Hello and welcome to WorldBuilding.SE! We have no idea what a perfect digital government would look like, as there is no such a thing as a "perfect government" right now. This means that your question might be put on hold as what we call "opinion-based". There is no way to somewhat objectively rate answers against each other. Especially the part about the name should be avoided. We try to build worlds, finding names is the task of the author. Maybe you could try to switch things around - give us your description of a perfect government and we will point out things that may be inconsistent.

Comment: Can try to sharpen your question and make it more specific?

Comment: Just a reminder: if others agree with me your question will first be "put on hold". This allows us to help you edit your question to fit the sites guidelines and prevents people from answering, as edits could possibly invalidate existing answers. If you have questions about the site please [take the tour](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour) and [visit the help center](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help). Also you can @Username someone to ping him and come to the chat to ask for help. Have fun!

Comment: Oh, and of course the post can be reopened once the question fits the guidelines. It's a standard procedure around here, as we are a bit different from other SEs.

Comment: I sometimes get a feeling that if you merged Worldbuilding.SE and Philosophy.SE, no one would notice a difference.